# How configure Doctrine to read namespace annotations?

Tags: doctrine-orm

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="games")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Games
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    .......
}
```

i get this fatal error : Message: "Class Games is not a valid entity or mapped super class."

But if i remove @ORM then it work. How can i configure it work with namespace ORM.

This is my config for doctrine : https://gist.github.com/a14bb5eb08073fa74857 , i use doctrine 2.2